# Different network alias ip on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-adapter, ubuntu-11.04

I have an Ubuntu server with only one NIC and an address `x.x.31.82` configured on it, the default gateway for it is `x.x.31.81` and the mask is `x.x.31.80/29`.

The problem is that I'm trying to configure another address `x.x.20.210` – the default gateway is supposed to be `x.x.20.209` but I'm unable to configure it on the server.

After I've configured `x.x.20.210` as an alias on the NIC, I've used the command

```
route add -net x.x.20.208 netmask 255.255.255.248 gw x.x.20.209
```

The route was added to the routing table but but I still can't access x.x.20.210 from the outside.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple IP on the same interface, the best way in my opinion is to add in `/etc/network/interfaces` something like that for the 2nd IP:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address x.x.20.210
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast x.x.20.255
    network x.x.20.0
    gateway x.x.20.209
```

And you shouldn't need to configure a route manually.
If you want to access it from the outside, don't forget to add this 2nd IP to `/etc/hosts` and if needed, to configure a DNS record for it.